# Lumen Request has session app('session') is empty. Redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, lumen

When taking the following store method on a lumen controller

```
public function store(Request $request, JwtToken $jwtToken, Redirector $redirector)
{
    $sessionData = $request->session()->all();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

In $sessionData all the data in the session is present including the previous url. When going through the default validator it calls `app('session')->previousUrl()` which returns `null`

When doing the same on `$request->session()` it is present. I have no clue if I messed something up or this is a bug in lumen.

I tried Redis and File driver.

Comment: You might need to post more information about your setup, because a quick test on a clean installation of Lumen works just fine and the previous URL is present, with both the session access methods you've described.

Comment: @Bogdan I found out that adding Redirector dependency to the method than ran `dd(app('session')->previousUrl());` when Redirector is present in the dependencies this returns `null` when you leave it out it returns the correct url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Lumen fixed by doing the following

```
public function store(Request $request, JwtToken $jwtToken)
{
    $sessionData = $request->session()->all();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    //use global redirect helper function
}
```

Removed the Redirector reference and used the global helper function

Answer (score 0):

You forget this on your `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
]);
```

Comment: isn't the problem its all ready in it seems `, Redirector $redirector`causes it to break. if you remove the redirector it works